# how to do authentication of xp clients on lion server with shared printers but windows server as a domain controller

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx-server, windows, network-printer

i have a LAN with windows xp clients and Windows Server 2008 R2 with server performing the domain authentication .

I also have a lion server with network shared printers attached to it .

The problem is i want to add the lion server to this LAN and also authenticate using windows server to access printers via lion server. it should show in status on the lion server which domain account has issued printing command on a printer .

Can anybody suggest any configuration ?

how to perform this type of authentication ?

Can i get all domain accounts and policies to Lion server and update if frequently and automatically with ease ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search shows that Apple.com has [the process documented](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4879).

Log in as an administrator to follow these steps. The first user account created in OS X Lion is an administrator account.

**To configure for Active Directory**

Add the Active Directory server to the list of DNS server:
1. Open System Preferences, choose Apple menu > System Preferences…
2. Choose View > Network.
3. If the padlock in the lower left is locked, click it and enter an administrator name and password to unlock.
4. Enter "DNS" in the search field and press return.
5. Click "+" under the "DNS servers:" pane, enter IP address of the Active Directory server.
6. Click "+" under the "Search Domains:" pane, enter Active Directory domain name.

**Bind to Active Directory server through Users & Groups pane:**

1. Open System Preferences, choose Apple menu > System Preferences…
2. Choose View > Users & Groups.
3. If the icon in the lower left is locked, click it and enter an administrator name and password to unlock.
4. Click "Login Options".
5. Click "Join…" button next to "Network Account Server:".
6. Enter the hostname of the Active Directory server, then click OK.
7. Enter credentials for the Active Directory server.
8. Execute the following Terminal command to enable the CUPS web interface:

   cupsctl WebInterface=yes

**Open the URL `http://localhost:631/printers` in Safari.**
For each printer you wish to share using Kerberos:
1. Click the printer name in the list.
2. Choose "Set Default Options" from the "Administration" pop-up menu.
3. Click "Policies".
4. Choose "kerberos" from the "Operation Policy:" pop-up menu.
5. Click "Set Default Options".

**Once you have completed this process, run this command in Terminal:**

```
cupsctl WebInterface=no
```